# Issue with subdomains and htaccess for SEO

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo, subdomain

I would like to change urls from:
`http://subdomain.domain.com/page/` to `http://subdomain.domain.com/?page=pagename`
and also:
`http://domain.com/page/` to `http://domain.com/?page=pagename`
though haven't had much success.

**Here is my htaccess file so far [updated]**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove 'www'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Add slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://resolutiongaming.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Subdomain redirect
RewriteRule ^/(webdev)/(.*)$ http://webdev.resolutiongaming.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(artwork)/(.*)$ http://artwork.resolutiongaming.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(music)/(.*)$ http://music.resolutiongaming.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Search engine optimization
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z]+)/$ ?page=$1
```

I used `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ ?page=$1` which seemed to work for the domain url but not the subdomain. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was an easy fix really. I basically put a .htaccess file in each subdomain directory that looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Search engine optimization
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z]+)/$ ?page=$1
```

Hope this helps someone. :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually had to do something like this recently. Try this for your **Subdomain redirect** block:

```
  RewriteRule ^/(webdev)/(.*)$ http://webdev.resolutiongaming.com/$2 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^/(artwork)/(.*)$ http://artwork.resolutiongaming.com/$2 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^/(music)/(.*)$ http://music.resolutiongaming.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Or maybe this; note the change from **$2** to **$1**:

```
  RewriteRule ^/(webdev)/(.*)$ http://webdev.resolutiongaming.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^/(artwork)/(.*)$ http://artwork.resolutiongaming.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^/(music)/(.*)$ http://music.resolutiongaming.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT:** Or Maybe try this. Note that you need to capture two parts of the URL to rewrite as you are explaining. Each item in parenthesis `(` and `)` corresponds to a string in the rewrite. Try this. Using your nicer regular expression `RewriteRule` as you mention in the comments:

```
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Or maybe this:

```
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)$ /$1/page=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ah I can see why I need that. But that doesn't fix the fact that `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ ?page=$1` doesn't seem to work on subdomains.

Comment: By that I mean it changes `http://resolutiongaming.com/webdev/page/` to `http://webdev.resolutiongaming.com/page/` which is what I want it to do but then that url is not changed to `http://webdev.resolutiongaming.com/?page=page`.