# .htaccess redirects: from old site with variables to Drupal & url aliases

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, mod-rewrite, redirect

Please look at the edits on this post. The last code examples I give are what I'm trying to accomplish. I have 147 lines of code that I'm working with. I guess I'm actually not trying to make a rule so much as I am trying to figure out redirects with those variables.

OK, I've been researching this for a few hours, and the regex apache rewrite rules get pretty specific and I'm stumped. Client has asked that the old site urls be rewritten/redirected to the new drupal site and corresponding pages that have url aliases. There are 147 variables (all 1 - 216 (out of sequence))
Example:
**I need**

```
/hardware/bikes.php?recordID=1 to redirect to http://www.bikerus.com/?q=hardware/first-bike-that-really-flies
```

**then**

```
/hardware/bikes.php?recordID=2 to redirect to http://www.bikerus.com/?q=hardware/second-awesome-bike-that-really-flies
```

**and so on**

**This is what I have so far:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^recordID=([0-9]+)$

RewriteRule ^/hardware/bikes\.php?recordID=%1$ http://www.bikerus.com/?q=hardware/first-bike-that-really-flies
```

This is obviously not working, any ideas ladies and chaps?

Ideally, it would be great if I could figure out another problem with Drupal I haven't figured out yet (for years). 
**Have a redirect that goes like this:**

```
redirect 301 /hardware/1.html   http://www.bikerus.com/hardware/first-bike-that-really-flies
```

**Instead of this:**

```
redirect 301 /hardware/1.html   http://www.bikerus.com/?q=hardware/first-bike-that-really-flies
```

But my first question is the priority now.
Thanks in advance.

**EDITS:**
The files I'm trying to redirect to aren't static, they're url aliases generated by Drupal's database.

In the end, yes, I will need to make 147 individual records (hardcoded), my question is how to do this:

```
redirect 301 /hardware/bikes.php?recordID=1   http://www.bikesrus.com/?q=hardware/random-bike-title-one
redirect 301 /hardware/bikes.php?recordID=2   http://www.bikesrus.com/?q=hardware/random-bike-title-two-ewhbcfn
redirect 301 /hardware/bikes.php?recordID=3   http://www.bikesrus.com/?q=hardware/random-bike-title-three-kxjhmuflr
redirect 301 /hardware/bikes.php?recordID=4   http://www.bikesrus.com/?q=hardware/random-bike-title-four-more-random-stuff
```

And for those that don't know, Drupal has a clean url rewrite rule that comes shipped with the .htaccess file that I'm currently editing:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So I need to be able to navigate this as well.

Comment: first-bike-that-really-flies is static?

Comment: This: `RewriteRule ^/hardware/bikes\.php?recordID=%1$` will never match because you are including the query in the regex.

Comment: Right, I know. I'm tinkering with it. I was just using that as a starting point. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the incoming URL does not hold the query to be added in the substitution URL (`random-bike-title-two-ewhbcfn`, for example) it is impossible to make a single general rule. Those parameters can't be guessed, so one solution is to hardcode 147 rules, as you say, or redirect all those incoming URLs, that seem to have a pattern (?), directly to a script.

Comment: YES! But what would that look like hard coded?

Comment: Please look at the edits on this post. The last code examples I give are what I'm trying to accomplish. I have 147 lines of code that I'm working with. I guess I'm actually not trying to make a rule so much as I am trying to figure out redirects with those variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} recordID=1
RewriteRule . http://www.bikesrus.com/hardware/bike-that-really-flies? [R=301,L]
```

**BOTH!! On my own, with a little more searching. The difference is that I put the word "hardcoded" into my search keywords this time. Thanks everyone who commented.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem to your second issue is that `redirect` really stinks for anything past a simple redirect. You need a `RewriteRule` to make this:

```
redirect 301 /hardware/1.html   http://www.bikerus.com/?q=hardware/first-bike-that-really-flies
```

More like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /?q=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or maybe this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)$ /?q=$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

But it’s not clear in your post where you are getting the `first-bike-that-really-flies` stuff from. So not to clear on how to handle that in Drupal. Very specific to your setup.

Actually just answered a `mod_rewrite` question similar to this [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658305/issue-with-subdomains-and-htaccess-for-seo/14658382#14658382). Might give you more insight.

Comment: Well the thing with Drupal is that they have a built in url alias-er. And it goes like this: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA] But when you try to write redirects on top of it it only works if you prepend the variable back onto the redirect (or you get a 404) like I cited in the second issue. Thanks for your time.